# LibreOffice Writer: Automatic Interpretation of Hyperlink Text from URL

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice, odt

One of the features I really like in Google Docs and some text editors (like [MarkText](https://github.com/marktext/marktext)) is their automatic interpretation of the text for a hyperlink.

You paste a URL into the document, and the editor automatically interprets a suitable hyperlink text from the url.

For example, if I paste this link into Google docs: https://github.com/garrettj403/SciencePlots

Google Docs allows you to replace the hyperlink text with its interpretation:

> GitHub - garrettj403/SciencePlots: Matplotlib styles for scientific plotting

**Reference:**

[image: Google Docs hyperlink text suggestion]

Does LibreOffice have a feature like this?
Is there an extension that provides a feature like this?